# Google Prettify Line numbers and Overflow

Tags: html, prettify, google-code-prettify

When adding overflow to Google prettify elements, the line numbers disappear.

Unchanged CSS:

```
pre
{    
    font-size:11px;
    background-color:white;
}
/* Alternate shading for lines */     li.L1,
li.L3,
li.L5,
li.L7,
li.L9 { background: #eee; width:200%;}
```

CSS & IMAGE BEFORE:

```
pre.prettyprint { padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #888;}
```

[image]

CSS & IMAGE AFTER:

```
pre.prettyprint { padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #888; overflow:auto;}
```

[image]

Comment: On what browser does this occur, and does it occur when you replace `overflow` with [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-y)?

Comment: @MikeSamuel - Thanks for your reply.  I've tried with Chrome, Firefox and Safari (no access to IE atm).  I've also changed the overflow to overflow-y - same issue on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the numbers were in the padding of the pre.prettyprint element.  If I increase the left padding to 30px with the overflow 'on', I can see the numbers.  I'll have to comb over the CSS some more (it was inherited)

CSS change & the resulting output:

```
pre.prettyprint { padding-left:30px; border: 1px solid #888; overflow: auto;}
```

[image]